# Error when trying to update an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using entity framework 4.3 in my MVC 3 application, when trying to update the entity(creating and deleting works fine) I am getting this error:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

When I got into debug mode I saw that on the [HttpPost] method no feed Id was supplied:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Feed feed)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(feed).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FolderId = new SelectList(db.Folders, "FolderId", "Name", feed.FolderId);
        return View(feed);
    }
```

although in the normal Get method the id in being passed. those are my entities

feed:

```
public class Feed
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int FeedId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be less then {1} charecters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must enter a valid link")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be less then {1} characters long.")]
    public string LinkUrl { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Folder")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="you must choose a folder")]
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }

    public Feed()
    {
        PublishDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

folder:

```
public class Folder
{    
    public int FolderId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "you must enter a folder name")]
    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "the {0} must be less then {1} charecters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have looked for a solution but none of them worked, like trying the refresh method, which doesn't exist in DbContext or defining a [Key] property above the FeedId and FolderId.

Comment: Do you have `FeedId` in your view? You must roundtrip its value for example in hidden field to get it back in HTTP Post.

Comment: Thank
that was my issue.
I added @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeedId) to my View

Comment: @Moran - You shouldn't be attempting to manage state yourself... It can result in problems, especially when multi-threading (eg in MVC) or using multiple contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be manually maintaining the entity state - change tracking should be performed by the context.

You're using a view model and assuming it should be attached to the database.

You need to do something like..,

```
Feed DbFeed = DBSet.Where(f => f.id = feed.Id);
DbFeed.Property = NewValue;
db.SaveChanges();
```

(excuse possibly incorrect syntax - I work in VB by default)

That is, get a new instance of the Feed object from the DB Context, then perform changes on the object you're given.

This is because the context doesn't actually give you a plain `Feed` object, but rather an anonymous type which wraps it and has the same properties. The wrapper overrides your methods and detects property changes which is how it maintains state.

The feed object you get back from your view doesn't contain this wrapper, hence the problems

Comment: Sorry not sure I agree with this. You're making a database round trip just to have EF start tracking `Feed` object with that particular id. You can simply just do `db.Feeds.Attach(feed);` then `db.Entry(feed).State = EntityState.Modified`

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework tracks objects, the feed you get from your view is untracked.  The pattern for this situation is to fetch the object you want to update from the db, then call UpdateModel which will apply the changes from your untracked entity to your tracked entity, which you can then save..

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var trackedEntity = db.Find(feed.Id)
        UpdateModel(trackedEntity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently but putting the [ScaffoldColumn(false)] attribute in my model it didn't create it in my view and there for the id was not passed.

I added `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FeedId)` to my model and that took care of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you were having concurrency problems. 
Your update state should be running as:

```
   UPDATE tableA SET colA = 'value' WHERE colX1 = 'compare1' AND colX2 = 'compare2';
```

This `colXn` could be your primary keys etc, or could be every column you are using. If you are not handling concurrency, if someone gets the data as the same time as you, alter and save it before you, your `WHERE` statement will never match, since the record information you are updating already has new information.